# How do you define a char array as a constant?

Tags: c++, c, arduino, constants

C/C++ noob here.  I've defined this in a header file...

```
typedef unsigned char BitChar[9]; // 8 data bytes (chars) and one width byte (char)

extern BitChar BitFont[];
```

and I have this in a cpp file...

```
BitChar BitFont[] = {
    B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,2, // 32 - Space
    B10000000,B10000000,B10000000,B10000000,B10000000,B00000000,B10000000,B00000000,1, // 33 - !
    ...
    B00000000,B00000000,B11100000,B11100000,B11100000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,3, // 127 - Unknown
};
```

It compiles and seemingly runs just fine.  However, since it will never change, I thought it should be marked as a constant.  How do I mark it as such?  What I expected, adding 'const', throws compile errors so I'm stumped.  Here's the error...

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'unsigned char (&)[9]' from expression of type 'const unsigned char [9]'
```

Comment: But it's not a string. It's binary data. Plus, I'm using this in Arduino and I'm not sure that's even available without including the std library, thus blowing up the size of the program too much for them.

Comment: I was not aware that you could initialize using `B000` notation...

Comment: Not sure why you need a specific `typedef` for a `char*` array just so it has some sort of specified range. The same declaration with `char BitFont[]` instead will work just fine.

Comment: Works fine. I use it all the time. Sure it's longer, but I find it much more readable than dec or hex when dealing with bitmasks and simple graphics like this since you're looking at the pixels directly.

Comment: I see the original comment suggesting I use std::string was deleted in case ppl are wondering what the heck I was talking about.

Comment: @merlin2011 neither was I. Is that a feature of the Arduino compiler?

Comment: @dlf, I am not able to get that notation to compile under `g++`, so I assume it must be Arduino compiler feature.

Comment: @merlin2011 [Yup](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/IntegerConstants)

Comment: Good to know about the B.  Thought that was a standard.  It really should be.

Comment: I'm not sure what compiler you are using but you should use `0b` to declare values in binary, not just `B`.

Comment: I suspect you have a function taking a `BitChar &` and you tried to pass it `BitFont[something]`, which doesn't work if `BitFont` is `const`.

Comment: @merlin2011: I suspect that this is not a "notation" at all. This is probably just a bunch of macros defined in some header file, specifically to compensate for the lack of binary constant support in C/C++ compilers. Yes, someone meticulously defined all 256 of them in that header. I could be wrong though. But if this is indeed a notation, why did they choose that unusual `B...` syntax that conflicts with normal identifier syntax? Why not adopt the already existing `0b...` syntax?

Comment: @AndreyT The (probably too hard to see) link in my previous comment goes to documentation showing that the `B` prefix is indeed an Arduino feature. Couldn't say why they didn't choose `0b` (though that's a gcc extension, for what it's worth).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add `const`. This

```
extern const BitChar BitFont[];
...
const BitChar BitFont[] = {
    B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,2, // 32 - Space
    B10000000,B10000000,B10000000,B10000000,B10000000,B00000000,B10000000,B00000000,1, // 33 - !
    ...
    B00000000,B00000000,B11100000,B11100000,B11100000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,3, // 127 - Unknown
};
```

should work perfectly fine in C. (Assuming that your compiler knows what these `B00000000` identifiers mean.)

This will also work perfectly fine in C++. The only potential for error in the C++ version is based on C++-specific properties of `const`.  If the definition does not see the declaration, then you have to specify the explicit `extern` in the definition as well

```
extern const BitChar BitFont[] = {
    B00000000
    ...
```

because in C++ `const` objects have *internal* linkage by default. However, if the declaration already contains the `extern` and the definition can see the declaration, then that `extern` in the definition is optional.

The error message you quoted suggests that somewhere in your code you are trying to initialize a reference of type `BitChar &` (aka `unsigned char (&)[9]`) with a const-qualified `BitChar` array. This will not work, since it violates the basic rules of const-correctness. The reference has to become const-qualified as well, i.e. it has to change to `const BitChar &` (aka `const unsigned char (&)[9]`).

Comment: Don't know if it makes a difference, but it's a cpp file, so its c++, but regardless, here's the exception I get when I add the const word just as you said...  Solix.ino:211: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'unsigned char (&)[9]' from expression of type 'const unsigned char [9]'
Solix.ino:218: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'unsigned char (&)[9]' from expression of type 'const unsigned char [9]'
Error compiling

Comment: @MarqueIV: The code you posted does not have any references in it. The code you posted will not generate this error. The source of this error is somewhere else.

Comment: lemme look around.  I believe I am using refs elsewhere.  I take it if I am I have to explicitly mark them as consts too?

Comment: you were correct.  When I explicitly added 'const' before my local variable refs as well as my function params which also were refs, it compiled.  Put that in an answer and I'll give the credit to you.

Comment: @MarqueIV: Yes, of course, If you declare your arrays as `const`, the reference type `unsigned char (&)[9]` will have to be changed to `const unsigned char (&)[9]` (aka `const BitChar &`)

Comment: @MarqueIV: Again, your question does not mention any references at all. Put it in your question and I will put it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the CONST's will still consume RAM space. For large constant arrays you may want to consider placing them into program space (aka Flash or non-volatile space). Below is an example.

```
const uint8_t BitFont[] PROGMEM = {
    B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,2, // 32 - Space
    B10000000,B10000000,B10000000,B10000000,B10000000,B00000000,B10000000,B00000000,1, // 33 - !
    B00000000,B00000000,B11100000,B11100000,B11100000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,3, // 127 - Unknown
};
#define BITFONT_X_SIZE (sizeof(BitFont)/sizeof(BitFont[0]))

void setup() {
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print(F("BitFont[] = "));
  for(int y = 0 ; y < BITFONT_X_SIZE ; y++) {
    Serial.print(pgm_read_byte_near( &(BitFont[1]) ) );
    Serial.print(F(","));
  }
  Serial.println("");
}
```

Note there are THREE things happening. First the PROGMEM macro is used by the avr-gcc to link this into program space. Second the pgm_read_byte_near function is used to read the pointer from program space. As it requires the use of a special opcode, to read program space.

Third and not directly related to your example, but similar is the F() function used in Serial.print()'s which likewise places the constant string into program space. Otherwise strings within the Serial.print consume static ram.

---

Alternatively you can create a matrix

```
#define BRICK_COLUMNS 9
const uint8_t BitFont[][BRICK_COLUMNS] PROGMEM = {
    {B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,2}, // 32 - Space
    {B10000000,B10000000,B10000000,B10000000,B10000000,B00000000,B10000000,B00000000,1}, // 33 - !
    {B00000000,B00000000,B11100000,B11100000,B11100000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,3} // 127 - Unknown
};
#define BITFONT_X_SIZE (sizeof(BitFont)/sizeof(BitFont[0]))

void setup() {
  Serial.println("");

  for(int x = 0 ; x < BITFONT_X_SIZE ; x++) {
    Serial.print(F("BitFont["));
    Serial.print(x);
    Serial.print(F("][y] = "));
    for(int y = 0 ; y < BRICK_COLUMNS ; y++) {
      Serial.print(pgm_read_byte_near ( &(BitFont[1]) ));
      Serial.print(F(","));
    }
    Serial.println("");
  }
  Serial.println("");
}
```

Comment: What are you achieving with your alternate matrix?  I actually already have one.  BitChar is a row of 9 chars and BitFont is 96 BitChars, thus forming a two-dimensional matrix of chars, albeit indirectly. Plus, I then have an explicit data type--BitChar--which I can use elsewhere whereas yours doesn't.  And finally, even though you've explicitly defined a two-dimensional uint8_t, you don't need the extra braces.  You can still initialize a multi-dimensional array with a single-dimension initializer.  Saves typing.

Comment: you can still use typedef in place of the uint8_t. The main point was to put the array into program(flash) space